# How to advertise a service on a port

Tags: linux, networking, services, hosting-services

I want to run a service(a server typically) on a host and it should advertise to other machines in the network.

Let's say I'm running a ReST service which provides the temperature based on location on a machine having IP 10.40.0.3 with Port 5000. User will configure the server address to "10.40.0.3:5000" on each client to access application. In some situations(like server configured to DHCP) it's hard to know the IP of server for normal user.

Is there any way that service can advertise itself so that user don't have to worry about IP address and PORT of server and he just have to scan and pick up server based on name? Like in Bluetooth, we only see the application supported Bluetooth devices based on UUID. If we see IoT devices, user always scan available devices and select a device (irrespective of IP:PORT).

What exactly I want is:
In one machine user install a server application and runs continuously in background. On other machines user install the client application. Client has to scan for server machine and show it to user. If user says okay then client configures to Server IP and Port addresses.

Comment: I would look into `avahi`/`zeroconf`.